# How to change web description in SPFx React webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, 2019

I'm writing an SPFx web part using React. I can get the description of the current web like this:

```
let desc = this.props.context.pageContext.web.description;
```

But how can I **change** the web description? The context object above is read-only, but I should be able to use a REST call using PnP or some JSOM-stuff. I've tried both with no luck, but I'm no expert and could use an example showing how to do it.

I'm on SharePoint 2019 (on premise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PnP JS to update the Web Properties. You need to set the `Description` property of web.

**Sample Example**:

```
import { Web } from "@pnp/sp";

let web = new Web("https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite");

web.update({
    Title: "New Title",
    Description: "My new description",
}).then(w => {
    console.log(w);
});
```

**Source**: [PnP JS - Update Web Properties](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/v1/sp/docs/webs/#update-web-properties)

---

**Using REST API**:

**Example**:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Web' }, 'Description': 'My new description'}",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Webs REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn499819(v=office.15))