# Change SharepointOnline site description with api call to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I need to change the description of a SharePoint site with a Power Automate flow. It is a really easy task with SharePoint online, it is kind of a nightmare with api call action "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint". I need to build the right API call and I don't know what to do.

I am digging in this windows documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service without amazing results.

For example I found out this object called SP.WebInformation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj244790(v=office.15)

And looking in the properties there is a "description" section. If I click there I see a get and set method. That is probably the right object to call but I am building in a bad way the APIrequest.

My flow looks like this now (see screenshot), but of course I have error 400 Invalid request.

[image]

Comment: Check REST API example given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289984/how-to-change-web-description-in-spfx-react-webpart/289987#289987) and try to replicate it in Power Automate (if it works).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Ganesh for your info!

I replicate the post, I change a bit and it works. I post the screenshot of my solution:

[image]

Ciao and thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you!!

Comment: I tried this & noticed that it only works for communication site & not working for team site. can you check it at your end if possible?