# Update Propertybag values in sharepoint using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, site-collection, site, property-bag

I need to update the Property bag values in sharepoint Using REST API. I am able to get the Values but not able to update.

Need help on this.

Comment: Are you trying to update SharePoint "site" property bag values? Which property you want to update? Are you trying this for communication site or team site?

Comment: Yes, We have custom Property bag values, We need to update one propertybag value using REST API

Comment: check my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289984/how-to-change-web-description-in-spfx-react-webpart/289987#289987. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property bags are read-only when using the REST API. If you want to update a property bag you will need to use the Client Object Model (CSOM) instead.

If you do a search for "sharepoint rest api property bags" you will see similar answers from StackOverflow and other forum sites.

Here is a JavaScript sample:

```
function setWebProperty() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    this.properties = web.get_allProperties();
    this.properties.set_item("myCustomProperty", "myCustomValue");
    ctx.load(web);
    web.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getWebProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
}

function getWebProperty() {
    alert(this.properties.get_item("myCustomProperty"));
}

function failedGettingProperty() {
    alert("failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using SharePoint REST API call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Web' }, 'Description': 'My new description'}",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
    "If-Match": "*"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

In this example I have updated description property of SharePoint online site.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Webs REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn499819(v=office.15))