# Setting a SharePoint Online's site "Title" property using the REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, site-collection, property-bag

I'm trying to set a SharePoint site's `Title` through the SharePoint REST API using C# code.

When I get the site's web data using:

```
GET http://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site-url/_api/web/
```

I get a response something like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site-url/_api/Web",
            "uri": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site-url/_api/Web",
            "type": "SP.Web"
        },
        // .... many more nodes here .....
        "Title": "my old title to be changed",
        // ... more data here
    }
}
```

Now I was hoping to change that SharePoint site's title by using this REST command:

```
POST http://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site-url/_api/web
```

with a body of

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Web"
    },
    "Title": "My new SharePoint site title here"
}
```

and headers:

```
Accept              application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type        application/json;odata=verbose
X-HTTP-Method       MERGE
If-Match            *
```

The command executed from Postman completes with an HTTP 200 - OK status - yet, when I go retrieve the title again:

```
GET http://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/site-url/_api/web/title
```

I still get back:

```
{
    "d": {
        "Title": "my old title to be changed",
    }
}
```

So it seems nothing really was changed at all ...

How can I change a SharePoint Online site's `Title` property through a REST API call?

Comment: What permissions do you have on the site?

Comment: The user is the owner of the site collection, and is also member of the site collection adminstrators group globally on our tenant. Therefore I really don't think it's a permission issue ...

Comment: Owner should be enough or site admin. SharePoint administrator role (tenant) doesn't automatically give you access to all sites by the way, you have to give yourself access to each site.

Comment: Personally, if I was building an app in C#, I would just use the PnP Core SDK https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/index.html or the newer Graph API wherever possible.

Comment: @CallumCrowley: can you show me how to do this with the MS Graph API? I've been able to retrieve some information - but on the root of my site, the only thing I see is the `displayName` - but that property is **read-only** - so what do I need to do to set the title to a new value?? Can you point to a blog post or post an answer here? I have a **really** hard time finding any meaningful samples of how to use the MS Graph with Sharepoint....

Comment: Hi @marc_s, did you try solution given below? Is it working for you?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP: no, it didn't work. But I'm suspecting it's a different problem all together - but the guy who could confirm this is away until next week ..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the techniques described in this blog post, but it's possible it may help you.

[How To Change The Site Title Of Modern SharePoint Team Site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-change-the-site-title-of-modern-sharepoint-team-site)

[image: Blog post]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint REST API call like below to update the SharePoint online site Title:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="updateSiteTitle()"> Update Site Title </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateSiteTitle() {
        var updateSiteTitleEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web";

        var payload = JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Web' },
            'Title': 'SPConnect - REST'
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: updateSiteTitleEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: payload,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Site Title updated successfully!");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I have just tried using it and it worked for me. You can adjust and use above code as per your requirements.

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [Update Propertybag values in sharepoint using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307394/update-propertybag-values-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api/307395#307395)